# Weaker Gupta-Bleuler conditon $<\psi|(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2|\psi> = 0$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-theory, brst

**Some context**

In the Gupta Bleuler quantization procedure for gauge fields we introduce the gauge fixing term:

$$S_{GB} = \int dV-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2$$

to the Lagrangian.

After quantization we see that this had extended the Hilbert space such that it contains negative norm states. We then impose:

$$\langle\psi|\partial_\mu A^{\mu-}|\psi\rangle = 0$$

for physical states $|\psi\rangle$. And indeed this eliminates all negative expectation values from the theory since $S_{GB} = 0$ for these states.

**Question**

I was wondering weather this isn't to strict of a constraint. If our only purpose is to remove the gauge fixing term $S_{GB}$ from the action, why can't we impose the weaker constraint:

$$\int dV\langle\psi|\partial_\mu A^{\mu\dagger}\partial_\mu A^{\mu-}|\psi\rangle = 0$$

This also ensures that $S_{GB}=0$ such that, in the end we have indeed quantized the original action !

Is there something that I am overlooking or is this indeed possible ? What pitfalls might I encounter when using this weaker constraint.

**The why...**

I am working on gauge fields in curved spaces and I found that the usual constraint cannot be implemented analytically while the weaker constraint can be implemented in an analytical fashion...

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for bra-ket notation please.

Comment: To clarify: for the original GB condition you use psi twice, usually int it used with two different states; I dont believe this to be equivalent. For your weaker condition: do you really want to integrate (opposed to the stronger condition)? what is your integration variable?

Comment: 1) I do think they are equivalent since the normal condition is(in2D) $e^{ikr}f(creators,k)|0>=0$ from which we than extract $<0|f(creators,k)^2|0>$. Writing $<0|\int dr e^{ikr - ik'r}f(creator,k)f(creator,k')|0> = 0$ is equivalent since we get a $\delta$.
2) I want to use it because my modes are eigenfunctions of $\partial_r^2$ but not $\partial_r$. The weaker condition allows me to partially integrate and use this property. 
3)The integration variable is the spatial volume V or in 2D just r.

Comment: So you confirm that one condition is with the integral, the other without? Can you write which term depends ob your integration variable explicetly?

Comment: To be exact I get something like: (in my specific case)

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dr \partial_r J_a(r) J_b(r)<0|f(creators)f(creators)|0>$ where f(creators) is some function of the creators that does not depend on r ! $J_a(r)$ is the Bessel function. As you see this expression in unwieldy but if we partially integrate we can use $\partial_r^2 J \sim J$ and all is good...

I know that there are also recursion relations for $\partial J$ but these are not suitable I really need eigenfunctions.

Comment: But I think that both constructions (with and without integral) are sufficient. To see this look at flat spacetime (which is the only experimental handle we have) in this case we get complex exponentials instead of Bessels and find what I wrote above. The integration sets k=k' and we obtain the usual better known stronger condition !

Comment: The form of the Gupta-Bleuler condition I know is $\partial \cdot A^- | \psi \rangle =0$ for any physical $\psi$. The minus does not here mean negative norm, but negative-frequency part of the longitudinal mode decomposition. This is then equivalent to $\langle \chi | \partial \cdot A | \psi \rangle$ for any pair of physical states $\psi, \chi$ (the occurrence and non-occurrence of minuses is important!). Also, in the usual bra-ket formalism there is really no space for an integral over volume, that is already implicitly included in the scalar product.

Comment: @Void sorry for my late respons didn't get a notification and deemed the question dead :/
I know that what you say is definitely correct. However I think that it is to strong. The term that is added to the Lagrangian to make it quantizable is $(\partial A)^2$ such that I think that it should be sufficient to demand that $\langle \psi |(\partial A)^2|\phi \rangle = 0$ for all physical states since this already ensures us that we are working in the Hilbert space of the original theory.